# Mysql UNION on wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need help to develop a wordpress customization. I have the following mysql query with `UNION` instruction:

```
SELECT 
    wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'dir_featured' ) 
WHERE 
    ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2151) ) AND 
    wp_posts.post_type = 'ait-dir-item' AND 
    ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND 
    ( 
        ( 
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'dir_featured' AND 
        CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'yes' 
        )
    ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
UNION
SELECT 
    wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'dir_featured' ) 
WHERE 
    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2151) AND 
    wp_posts.post_type = 'ait-dir-item' AND 
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND 
    mt1.post_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

I want to translate this query with wordpress parameters. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "translate this query with wordpress parameters" ? Could you please clarify?

Comment: I intend to write it with the parameters of wordpress as this sample


 $params = array(
  'post_type'   => 'ait-dir-item',
  'nopaging'   => true,
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
     'key' => 'dir_featured',
     'value' => 'yes',
     'compare' => '='
    ), 
    array(
     'key' => 'dir_featured',
     'value' => '',
     'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
   ) ,
  'orderby'    => array( 'dir_featured' => 'DESC','post_date' => 'ASC'  ),
  'post_status'  => 'publish',
  'tag__in'   => $queried_object ->term_id
 );

Comment: Why are you using a LEFT JOIN to wp_postmeta when you require a record from wp_postmeta? Why is there a LEFT JOIN to a second instance of wp_meta in the first query when it is never used?

Comment: hello, I started from the query that generates wordpress and I changed to my liking. joins and all are the result of the parameters that I wrote above.

this instruction used to print the query

var_dump($itemsQuery->request);

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this query ? 
Here is your query in Wordpress mode

```
$args = array(
    'cat'            => 2151,
    'post_type'      => 'ait-dir-item',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'dir_featured',
                    'value'   => 'yes',
                    'compare' => '==',
                ),
            ),

);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Hello , thank you for the answer but your parameters correspond only to the first query , but do not take into account the "UNION " and the next query . I need to translate that query to display some items " sponsored " ordered in a certain way . The result of the query posted is exactly what I want to achieve .
I think we are on track ... Thanks again for the help